# EmberJS good way of accessing child views from event handler

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I've been experimenting with EmberJS lately (big fan of its amazing bindings framework) and I've written a test GUI for starting and displaying the status of some kind of general asynchronous process (like an AJAX request for example, but it could be something different)

http://jsfiddle.net/whoward/fLCDj/

I found myself fighting the framework a bit to be able to access the child view I wanted from inside my click event handler which is probably a good indication I'm not following a best practice.

Any suggestions? (the code I'm talking about specifically is the indicatorView property which is needed inside the event handler named "process")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a technical standpoint, you could have the child view set itself on the parent when the child is created:

```
  init: function() {
    this._super();
    this.get("parentView").set("indicatorView", this);
  }
```

However, this is a big code smell, and all of this strikes me as a rather convoluted architecture. I've reworked your example to include a controller that acts as an intermediary for your model and views: http://jsfiddle.net/dgeb/9QbX3/

I did this quickly and I'm sure it could be refactored further. In general, try to keep logic flowing from V -> C -> M -> C -> V. Parent views, or parent objects in general, shouldn't be dependent on their children.